# A timer which auto-click this button every 20seconds

Tags: android, button

I have this button which i want to set a timer to it so that the user do not have to click it everytime, such that it auto click this button every 20seconds. How do i set it?

Basically i am using a tabhost activity, so there're total of 3 tabs. In the first tab, there is this button which i need to click the button therefore i then able to retrieve informations from webservice and this webservice will update every time. When i click on other tabs and back to the first tab, i want it to be auto refresh.. Instead of clicking the button to refresh.

```
            holder.btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
             }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient way IMO is using [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
private void doTheActualJobWhenButtonClicked() {
  // put whatever you need to do when button clicked here
  ... ...
}

... ...

holder.btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // job triggered by user click button:
    doTheActualJobWhenButtonClicked();
  }
});

... ...

ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

// This schedule a task to run every 20 seconds:
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // job triggered automatically every 20 seconds:
    doTheActualJobWhenButtonClicked();
  }
}, 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

UPDATE:
If your button click perform some UI update for example refresh text in a TextView, then simply wrap 
your method call within runOnUiThread():

```
private void doTheActualJobWhenButtonClicked() {
  myTextView.setText("refreshed");
}

ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
// This schedule a task to run every 20 seconds:
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // involved your call in UI thread:
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        doTheActualJobWhenButtonClicked();
      }
    });        
  }
}, 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Also you need shutdown ScheduledExecutorService properly before open next Activity or close your current Activity:

```
// Shut down scheduled task before starting next activity
if (scheduleTaskExecutor != null)
  scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdownNow();
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

... ...

public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  // Shut down scheduled task when closing current activity
  if (scheduleTaskExecutor != null)
    scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdownNow();
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This is nice and clean, but I think using a self-created `Thread` would be more flexible, since you can dynamically change the rates and latencies, etc.

Comment: hey see my codes again. i have posted it. i want the button to auto click every 20seconds without me clicking it.

Comment: It isn't working. Previously i can retrieve information from the webservice but after these coding, i got back a null. However i click on other tabs, but when i click back the particular tab , the whole app stucked.

Comment: @sowhat, answer updated. Consider people's answer as a pseudocode, better to learn and understand the API behind the code, get a coffee and try to solve it yourself.

Comment: thank you. But im having an error now. public void onDestroy().

Comment: @sowhat, it is better to open new thread for new question, rather than ask in comments here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a button, I assume that you have an `ActionPerformed`-type method at someplace.

Given that, you can do this:

```
public class AutoClick extends Thread {
  // Time to wait in milliseconds
  private long wait;

  //Latency excepted
  private long lat;

  AutoClick(long time, long latency) {
    wait = time;
    lat = latency;
  }

  public void run() {
    long start = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();

    long current;
    while(true)
      current = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
      long step = (current-start) % 20000;
      if(step <= latency || step >= wait-latency)
        //call the action-performed method
  }
}
```

Then create an instance of the thread and run it:

```
public AutoClick clicker = new AutoClick(20000);

clicker.run();
```

Comment: hey, see my codes again. I want this button to autoclick using timer. What should i put?